# Thinktecture IdServer V3 and Client Configuration from Database

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

Hi I am using Thinktecture IdServer V3 and I have a question regarding configuring custom Client Configuration from database. Is this possible similar to a view service or a user service (i.e IViewService Or IUserService)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is similar. Here is the documentation. http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/ef/clients_scopes.html